# How to read and share a Deezer Playlist with the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, dictionary, sdk, nsjsonserialization, deezer

I am reading the user's info by following Deezer Documentation and making a request with the servicePath "user/me". I get the User ID and try to make a request with the path:

```
NSString* playlistPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"playlist/%@", self.deezerID];
DeezerRequest* request = [_deezerConnect createRequestWithServicePath:playlistPath
                                                                params:nil
                                                              delegate:self];

[_deezerConnect launchAsyncRequest:request];

NSLog(@"Path: %@", playlistPath);
```

An I receive the information from this:

```
/* Delegate methods */
#pragma mark - DeezerRequestDelegate
- (void)request:(DeezerRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSData *)data {


NSError *error;
id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSDictionary *jsonDic = (NSDictionary *)myJSON;

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", jsonDic);
}

self.deezerID = jsonDic[@"id"];

}
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
Dictionary: {
error =         {
    code = 800;
    message = "no data";
    type = DataException;
    };
}
```

What does this mean? Am I making a correct request in order to retrieve the user's playlists and its tracks?

What I want to do is to get the USERs Playlists and allow him to share it to a WebService to another User. Is this even possible?

Comment: That "`playlistPath`" line isn't the entire URL you're working with.  What does the URL come out to be, before you make the POST or request to get the playlist?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question in order to include the complete URL . I hope that helps to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query the user endpoint instead: user/USER_ID/playlists.
You can use the playlist endpoint only with playlist ids.
Documentation is here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/playlists